# how to send command function from server in android without sending request?

Tags: javascript, cordova

How can I send command from server to android app(hybrid app) without directly requesting it. i have an app that is currently use time interval every 10 second.The function is send request use ajax to get recent update from my server. The problem is my server will heavy load if many apps send request simultaneously.can my server actually send command or anything that can run function to update the data itself.So i can stop the time interval, just send data if there is anything changed at my server side.

Comment: Not really, where would you send your data to if there was no request for it? There are ways to reduce the load, like your app could send requests like "has something changed since my last request"? If server reports false, then just ignore, if it's true, then send another request for details. And on your server you'd have something like "last changed" with a date.

Comment: maybe to any user that login into my server..cause my apps got login thing..so apart form reduce server load, my idea will never had chances to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sockets for solve you problem.

Comment: what kind of socket?i cant understand what socket means

Comment: Socket - connection

Socket for Android
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

Schema: 
In your app you define callbacks for server messages.

And you need to make socket app on server

Comment: i can apply this thing into hybrid apps?i don't know single thing about java.

Comment: Read docs, so only sockets allows you to get data from server without request from app.